# Linearity assumption OLS

Tags: least-squares

One of the OLS assumptions, "linearity", is often stated as equating each observation of the dependent variable with a linear combination of the independent variables plus some error term.

What confuses me here is that I don't quite understand how this is actually imposing any assumption if there are no constraints on the error term. The error term is just the value that makes the equation correct for each observation. What is this assumption actually telling us?

Comment: But there *are* strong constraints on the error terms!  Please review our [threads about regression assumptions.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+assumption+error+score%3A10)

Comment: I am referring only to the first assumption, which does not include any constraints on the error term (at least not in Greenes book)

Comment: But by ignoring the other assumptions you are falsely characterizing the error, which is what leads you astray.